# Change Alpha on a Color object

Tags: java, android, alpha

Is there a way to add aplha to color that i can get from a color string.
Because now i can draw my color without the alpha by using the following code

```
      CircleOptions options = new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(car.getLatitude(), car.getLongitude()))
          .radius(car.getRadius())
          .strokeColor(Color.argb(50,232,245,248))
          .strokeWidth(2)
          .fillColor(Color.parseColor(car.getColorString()));
```

This works fine. But i want to make the color more transparent. Is there a good way to add alpha do this color because i can only get out a "ColorString"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color is represented as a int and you can represent it with hex notation like 0xAARRGGBB, which means Alpha, Red, Green, Blue. So each value can be 0 to 255.

Thus, what you want can be achieved with some bit operations.

If you want reset alpha value then,

```
int newColor = 0x10000000 | (Color.parseColor(car.getColorString()) & 0xFFFFFF);
```

(0x10000000 means new alpha value - 16 which is about 6.274% alpha because 100% is 255)
(0xFFFFFF means we take only rgb value from a color)

[See also](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the alpha of a colour in android with two extra digits on hex code of the colour.

Take a look at the [official colour documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)

All you need is applying the following rules :

> The value always begins with a pound (#) character and then followed
> by the Alpha-Red-Green-Blue information in one of the following
> formats:
>
> ## RGB
>
> ## ARGB
>
> ## RRGGBB
>
> ## AARRGGBB